# Fetching SQL records

Tags: php, mysql, database, fetch

Ah, I wrote a script, but I forgot already how to fetch MySQL records... so... I get problem with this

RESOURCE id#X

```
$QUERY = "SELECT id FROM WORKING TABLE VARIABLE WHERE username='WORKING USERNAME VARIABLE' and password='WORKING PASSWORD VARIABLE'";
$QUERY1 = mysql_query($QUERY);
$myusername = $QUERY1
echo $myusername;
```

I know I have to fetch it here. I tried many ways on internet. But none of them works. Mean through I get NOTHING as result back. Help please?

Without this code... I get everything, like password, email and username (alpha version).

Comment: Do you really have 'WORKING TABLE VARIABLE' as part of your query or are you replacing that before you run it?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [**prepared statements**](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Offcourse not! I replaced it to prevent recognizing the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$QUERY = "SELECT id FROM WORKING TABLE VARIABLE WHERE username='WORKING USERNAME VARIABLE' 
and password='WORKING PASSWORD VARIABLE' ";
$QUERY1 = mysql_query($QUERY);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($QUERY1))
  {
  echo $row['id'];//you are selecting id not username
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  $QUERY = "SELECT * FROM WORKING TABLE VARIABLE WHERE username='WORKING USERNAME VARIABLE' and password='WORKING PASSWORD VARIABLE'";
   $QUERY1 = mysql_query($QUERY);
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($QUERY1))
  {
   $row['username'] =  $myusername;
    echo $row['username'];
  }
```

Comment: he's selecting id not username?

Comment: there was no quer first :)

Comment: @RikTelner - haha.. sorry really didn't mean it :)

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan Absolutely no problem. It's understandable. Mistakes happen everywhere ;).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
echo $myusername[0]['id'];
```

If you want to actually fetch a single result like this, I'd use mysqli_fetch_object.